# Why does my camera clip into the player object when rotating around it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, cinemachine

I'm trying to create a camera that looks around the player, with a fixed distance.

I've got a fair bit, but when rotating around my object horizontally, the camera clips into my object.
This does not happen when rotating around the object at an angle (looking from above/down).

Note that the player visual object, and the target that the camera is following is NOT a child of the visual player object. They are both a child of parent, and can move independently.

```
                      PlayerParent
                           |
           ==================================
           |                                |
       PlayerVisual                      CameraTarget
```

I really cant find out why this happens.

```
void Start()
    {
        _camera = GetComponent<CinemachineVirtualCamera>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        RotateHorizontal();
        RotateVertical();
    }

    void RotateVertical()
    {
        var _rotationPower = 2f;

        _camera.Follow.rotation *= Quaternion.AngleAxis(Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * _rotationPower, Vector3.right);

        var angles = _camera.Follow.eulerAngles;
        angles.z = 0;

        var angle = _camera.Follow.eulerAngles.x;

        //clamp rotation.
        if (angle > 180 && angle < 340)
        {
            angles.x = 340;
        }
        else if (angle < 180 && angle > 40)
        {
            angles.x = 40;
        }

        _camera.Follow.eulerAngles = new Vector3(angles.x, _camera.Follow.eulerAngles.y, 0);
    }

    void RotateHorizontal()
    {
        var _rotationPower = 2f;
        _camera.Follow.Rotate(new Vector3(0, Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * _rotationPower, 0), Space.Self);
    }
```

Any help with understanding why this happens is greatly appriciated!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, I had to add the player visual to the ignore collision list.
The camera was bumping into the different player components.